# Can't get P3.1 of a MSP430F5529 to go high

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

I've got an MSP430F5529 which I'm trying to interface with an ADS1231. I wasn't getting any feedback from the ADC so I figured I would go back to something simple. I'm stepping through a simple blink program which toggles the pin. I can get P3.3 to go high at 3.2V, but I can't ever get more than 32mv on P3.1, or 72mv when P3REN is enabled. What am I not getting?

I've already realized that I've got a flaw in my USB implementation, PUR isn't attached to USBDP so it's very possible that I've also done something silly here. The board passed etest, and was professionally assembled.

```
#include <msp430.h>             

int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;
    P6SEL = 0x00;
    P6DIR |= 0xFF;
    P3DIR |= 0xFF;
    P6OUT = 0xFF;
    P3OUT = 0xFF;

    for(;;) {
        volatile unsigned int i;

        P6OUT ^= 0xFF;
        P3OUT ^= 0xFF;

        i = 10000;
        do i--;
        while(i != 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Shouldn't you first set function pin to I/O by writing to P3SEL register? Same as with P6SEL?
See on page 329: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf

Comment: So it's 0x00 by default, which is GPIO. I did do an iteration where I was explicitly setting it and it made no difference. I also verified that the register was set correctly via JTAG. I'm really hoping it's some simple software bug.

Comment: Have you discarded a faulty MCU or having burned the GPIO? Do you have another board for testing? It happened to me once with an MSP, the only difference is that I know the GPIO was working before. Double check with a different MCU even if it's not the same board (a dev kit or similar if you have one at hand), so you can discard a software issue.